# How to make a center fullscreen loader

Tags: css, position, fixed, loader

My loader position not in middle center, please change my code. (im sorry my english is bad haha). ok senior designer, this my code.

```
.loader-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 9999999999;
}
```

[this is preview of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjSf4.png), can you make this in center middle position? please, this my first project hehe :)

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the container as overlay to span the entire viewport just use `position: fixed; inset: 0;` which is shorter and easier.

To center the loader use Flexbox. `justify-content` aligns the child elements along the main-axis (flex direction) and `align-items` along the cross axis.

`top: 50%` does not work correctly in your case as percentages are always relative to the parent element. By default an elements height will be `auto` or which is `undefined` and calculated to `fit-content`. 50% of undefined is also undefined!

```css
.loader {
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.loader-container {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-container">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```